# Trivia game with JFrame

Tags: java, jframe

I'm trying to make a trivia game. My problem is that, the questions does not show up in the frame when I try to run the program. what should I do? Here's what I have done so far. any help would really be great. thanks in advance.

```
package trivia;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class ChemistryJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    String question, answer;
    ChemistryJFrame[] questionbank = new ChemistryJFrame[3];
    List<ChemistryJFrame> questionlist = Arrays.asList(questionbank);
    int quest;

    public ChemistryJFrame() {
        initComponents();  
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")


    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        dispose();
        MainJFrame Main = new MainJFrame();
        Main.setVisible(true);

    }                                        

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ChemistryJFrame bank = new ChemistryJFrame();
        bank.banklist();
        bank.startquiz();
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ChemistryJFrame().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public void banklist()
    {
        questionbank[0] = new ChemistryJFrame();
        questionbank[0].question = "Which of the following scientists was awarded the Nobel Prize in 1911 for the discovery of the radioactive elements, radium and polonium?\n A) Charles Darwin\n B) Dmitri Mendeleev\n C) Marie Curie";
        questionbank[0].answer = "C";

        questionbank[1] = new ChemistryJFrame();
        questionbank[1].question = "How many electrons can occupy an s orbital?\n A) one\n B) two\n C) three";
        questionbank[1].answer = "B";

        questionbank[2] = new ChemistryJFrame();
        questionbank[2].question = "Which noble gas has the highest melting point ?\n A) argon\n B) xenon\n C) radon";
        questionbank[2].answer = "C";
    }

    public void startquiz()
    {
        for(quest=1; quest<10; quest++)
        {
            questionlabel.setText(questionbank[quest].question);
        }
    }



    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JSeparator jSeparator1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel questionlabel;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: In the ChemistryJFrame constructor there is a method call `initComponents()`, but you do not have that method listed.  That's where the magic should be happening, so it really depends on that method.

Answer (score 0):

Your start quiz function seems totally wrong to me.

At the moment you are seeing nothing because the quiz start function is very rapidly setting the text to every question - finally ending at question 9 which is blank as you never set it in the banklist function.

I would imagine that you intend to set the text to the qustion[0] text and then wait for some kind of user response?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void startquiz()
{
  for(quest=1; quest<10; quest++)
  {
    questionlabel.setText(questionbank[quest].question);
  }
}
```

Lots of issues:

- You are iterating from 1 to 10, but you only define `questionbank` as an array of 3 items. `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` is being thrown.
- Even if the above is solved, you just iterate all questions before the data is even displayed. You would only get to see the last one. Learn to program with listeners, this is how GUIs work (not sequentially as command line programs).
- You also have what seems to be an `actionListener` method for a button that does not exist, clean your code.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually create `questionlabel`. You need to create it first and then add it to the frame.
Also in this piece of code:

```
for(quest=1; quest<10; quest++)
    {
        questionlabel.setText(questionbank[quest].question);
    }
```

You'll be overwriting label text 10 times and only the last question will be shown. What you probably need is ten different labels.
Another thing is that you create only 3 questions, but iterate over 10. Arrays in Java start with zero so you need to change `for(quest=1` to `for (quest=0`

Those are not all of the problems with your code, but keep trying, you'll get there eventually :)